# SET SHOWPLAN_ALL where does it come from?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

We have a C# webservice that uses a SQL Server 2014 as data storage. We use LINQ most places but also a bit of raw SQL.

Recently we started logging our SQL statements on the DB side and we noticed a lot of "SET SHOWPLAN_ALL" that are part of the same batch as the actual queries. This generates a lot of SQL errors because our DB user does not have the rights to do a "SET SHOWPLAN_ALL".

Does anyone know why we would have "SET SHOWPLAN_ALL" as part of our SQL batches? Is it something that LINQ generates? Could it be something that our New Relic APM agent injects to monitor SQL queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your DB statements log ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that this is something the New Relic APM agent does when a query takes longer than 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL
```

It makes SQL Server not to execute the T-SQL, instead it returns details about  execution of the statement. You can find more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx) including examples how it can be called.

Quite possibly this has been left over in the batch as it has been optimized for performance. To "switched if off" to my knowledge the batch needs to be analysed and the statement removed from the batch.